# Подсчет числа файлов в подкаталоге и вывод в QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Есть структура каталогов вида `dir/subdir[n]/file[m]`. Необходимо получить имя каталога `dir`, все имена каталогов `subdir` и подсчитать числов файлов в каталогах `subdir`. Собранную информацию необходимо вывести в `QTableWidget` в формате:

```
DIR| SUBDIR | count_file_SUBDIR
  a      b            5
  a      c            6
  a      r            7
```

На данный момент получается только посмотреть, сколько файлов в каталоге `DIR` (т.е. обойти всё дерево и вернуть число файлов).

Проблема именно в обходе подкаталогов и выводе информации о них.

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_download_clicked(bool)
{

QString src = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory();

  std::string dir;

  std::string subdir = "SUBDIR";//заглушка

  int cf = 0;//число файлов в каталоге

  download_key(src, serial_number, cf);

  QString ck = QString::number(cf);

  QString sn = QString::fromStdString(dir);

  QString tp = QString::fromStdString(subdir);

  QTableWidgetItem* newItem1 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(sn));

  QTableWidgetItem* newItem2 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(ck));

  QTableWidgetItem* newItem5 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(tp));

  QTableWidgetItem* newItem3 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(sn));

  QTableWidgetItem* newItem4 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(ck));

  QTableWidgetItem* newItem6 = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(tp));


  qDebug() << "KEY" << ck << sn << tp << t_col << t_row;

  ui->key_tableView->setRowCount(t_row + 1);

  ui->key_tableView_2->setRowCount(t_row + 1);

  ui->key_tableView->setItem(t_row, t_col, newItem1);

  ui->key_tableView_2->setItem(t_row, t_col, newItem3);

  t_col = 1;

  ui->key_tableView->setItem(t_row, t_col, newItem5);

  ui->key_tableView_2->setItem(t_row, t_col, newItem6);

  t_col = 2;
  ui->key_tableView->setItem(t_row, t_col, newItem2);

  ui->key_tableView_2->setItem(t_row, t_col, newItem4);


  ++t_row;

  t_col = 0;

}

void download_key(QString src,std::string& dir,int& cf)
{

     QString src_path = QDir(src).absolutePath();

     QDirIterator it(src_path,QDir::NoDotAndDotDot| QDir::Files
                  , QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
     int count_f = 0;

     while(it.hasNext())
     {
          qDebug() << it.next();

          ++count_f;
     }


     QString Qserial_number = QDir(src).dirName();

     serial_number=Qserial_number.toUtf8().constData();

     cf=count_f;
}
```

Comment: А почему вы не используете QDir?

Comment: QDir не использовал т.к. мне нужно было получить число файлов для этого достаточно итератора, но в силу тупика в решении, буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{QTextStream cout(stdout);

    QString mainPath = "/";//Указываете свой путь

     QDir dir;

     QStringList namesOfDirectories;

     dir.setPath(mainPath);

    `введите сюда код` namesOfDirectories = dir.entryList();//Получили список

     namesOfDirectories.removeFirst();

     namesOfDirectories.removeFirst();//Первые два елемента "."

     for (int i=0; i < namesOfDirectories.size(); ++i)
     {
        dir.cd(namesOfDirectories[i]);

        QStringList fileNames;//Список файлов

        int count;//Количество файлов в папке

        fileNames = dir.entryList();

        fileNames.removeFirst();

        fileNames.removeFirst();

        count = fileNames.size();

        cout<<namesOfDirectories[i]<<endl;

        dir.cdUp();

        for (int j=0; j < count; ++j)
        {

             cout << fileNames[j] << endl;

        }

        cout << count << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, баги вижу. Вам все таки нужно воспользоваться советом Bearded Beaver и использовать QDir::NoDotAndDotDot вместо removeFirst();

Comment: уже воспользовался, всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
QTextStream cout(stdout);
QString mainPath = ".";//Указываете свой путь
QDir dir;

QStringList namesOfDirectories;

dir.setPath(mainPath);
dir.cdUp();
dir.cd("dir");
namesOfDirectories = dir.entryList();//Получили список
namesOfDirectories.removeFirst(); namesOfDirectories.removeFirst();//Первые два елемента "."

for (int i(0); i < namesOfDirectories.size(); i++){
    dir.cd(namesOfDirectories[i]);
    QStringList fileNames;//Список файлов
    int count;//Количество файлов в папке
    fileNames = dir.entryList();
    fileNames.removeFirst();  fileNames.removeFirst();
    count = fileNames.size();
    for (int j(0); j < count; j++){
        cout << fileNames[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Это грубый но рабочий пример.

Comment: dir.cdUp();
dir.cd("dir"); Моете убрать. Это подходит только в моем случае.

Comment: Для удаления . и .. есть флаг QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, fileNames.removeFirst() это костыль

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: спасибо за пример. нашел баги, поправил см.ниже.